# Some friends of mine are building their own house. (meaning of the sentence)

Tags: sentence-meaning

> **Some friends** of mine are building **their own house**.

Is it idiomatic sentence about a pair? If I understand right, some people are building one house, not two or more houses. So, it means a pair, right? But I don't understand why do we use "some" for two people. I guess "some" is more than two. If the sentence were the following one, it would be more clearly. Right?

> Two friends of mine are building their own house.

P.S. The first sentence is from my grammar book.

Comment: Are you asking whether the top sentence *necessarily means* two people, or whether it *can mean* two people?

Comment: In this context, *some* isn’t about the number (other than it is unspecified). It is about membership in the group “my friends”. [being one, a part, or an unspecified number of something (such as a class or group)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/some). I wouldn’t assume a couple (although many would) because you chose not to say ‘two of’. It could be 4 roommates building a house together for all I know. I’d probably ask you to clarify if we were having a conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionaries say that *some* is *an unspecified number.* You are right that, in this context, it would be assumed to mean a married/cohabiting couple, or possibly a family. Yes, if we wanted to make it absolutely clear we could say 'Two friends...' or 'A couple  I know...'

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm trying to understand: Is it idiomatic to use "some friends/people" for a pair?

Comment: Yes - I would have said so if it wasn't.  (We usually use _couple_ rather than _pair_ in this context.)

Comment: It seems that "some friends of mine" can be just 1 friend, right?

Comment: No - if it was only one we would say "**A** friend".